# How add and subtract days using Moment JS for the given timestamp value?

Tags: javascript, momentjs, moment-timezone

I have unixtimestamp value 1628312400000 // 7th Aug 2021

```
var selectedDate = moment(1628312400000);
let formattedDate = moment.tz(day, "America/Chicago").format('DD-MM-YYYY')+ " " +"00:00:00"; //07-08-2021 00:00:00
```

Now, I want the previous day and the next day of the same timestamp.

So, I tried as below,

```
let nextDay = moment(selectedDate).add(2, 'days').valueOf();//1628398800000
let yesterDay = moment(selectedDate).subtract(1, 'days').valueOf();// 1628226000000

let yest = "Yesterday :: "+moment.tz(yesterDay, "America/Chicago").format('DD-MM-YYYY')+ " " +"00:00:00";// getting invalid date
let next = "Next Day :: "+moment.tz(nextDay, "America/Chicago").format('DD-MM-YYYY')+ " " +"23:00:00";// getting invalid date
```

I am getting the output as ,

```
Yesterday :: Invalid date 00:00:00
Next Day :: Invalid date 00:00:00
```

expected result

```
Yesterday :: 06-08-2021 00:00:00
Next Day :: 09-08-2021 23:00:00
```

Kindly, help/guide me where I am doing the mistake here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Liam, add and substract working, let yesterDay = moment(selectedDate).add(2, 'days').valueOf();// 1628226000000
let nextDay = moment(selectedDate).subtract(1, 'days').valueOf();// 1628398800000. after that below statements are not working, let yest = "Yesterday :: "+moment.tz(yesterDay, "America/Chicago").format('DD-MM-YYYY')+ " " +"00:00:00";// getting invalid date
let next = "Next Day :: "+moment.tz(nextDay, "America/Chicago").format('DD-MM-YYYY')+ " " +"23:00:00";// getting invalid date

Answer (score 0):

You my use this functions to your problem

```js
var PropsDataSelected = '2021-08-01' // this will be the user data selected

var date = new Date(PropsDataSelected); // this will set the selected date

Date.prototype.Nextday = function(days) { // this will add days to the selected data
    var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
    return date;
}
Date.prototype.PrevDay = function(days) { // this will remove days from data selected
    var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
    date.setDate(date.getDate() - days);
    return date;
}
console.log('curr date: ', date); // this is the curr date selected
console.log('next date: ', date.Nextday(1)); // this is the number of days you want to add
console.log('prev date: ', date.PrevDay(1)); // this is the number of days you want to remove
```

In case you want moment you can use like this:

```js
document.getElementById("dateDisplay").innerHTML = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
var nowPlusOneDay = moment().add('days', 1);
var nowPrevOneDay = moment().subtract('days', 1);
var nowPlusOneDayStr = nowPlusOneDay.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
var nowPlusPrevDayStr = nowPrevOneDay.format('YYYY-MM-DD');

console.log('Next: '+nowPlusOneDayStr);
console.log('Prev: '+ nowPlusPrevDayStr);
```

```html
<div id="dateDisplay"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you NoobDev for your code and time. Got an idea in Javascript also from you. The only thing is you are mentioned from the current day instead of user-given data input.

Comment: @VadivelA i have changed the code in js exemple , the firsst one, see if is ok now

Answer (score 0):

Here's how, just add and subtract directly using your `selectedDate`

```js
var selectedDate = moment(1628312400000);

let next = "Next Day :: " + moment(selectedDate, "America/Chicago").add(2, 'days').format('DD-MM-YYYY') + " " + "23:00:00"; // getting invalid date
let yest = "Yesterday :: " + moment(selectedDate, "America/Chicago").subtract(1, 'days').format('DD-MM-YYYY') + " " + "00:00:00"; // getting invalid date

console.log(yest)
console.log(next)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi Alexandre, Really, Thanks for your time and code. Actually, my code also working. I did some minor mistake in the import. After that it worked. Same your code reduced my two lines. Thank you. One point to mention that, in your code yesterday you are adding 23:00:00 instead of next day. remaining everything fine.

Comment: @VadivelA indeed, I updated my answer. Happy to help mate. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You could get the date from millisecs and store it into `selectedDate`; then `add` and `subtract` starting from this Date:

```js
var selectedDate = new Date(moment(1628312400000));
console.log(moment(selectedDate).add(2, 'days').format('DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss'));
console.log(moment(selectedDate).subtract(1, 'days').format('DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could format the given timestamp by chaining methods to get previous day and the next day date values.

```js
let selectedDate = moment(1628312400000);
let formattedDate = moment.tz(selectedDate, "America/Chicago").format("DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss");
let nextDay = moment.tz(selectedDate, "America/Chicago")
  .add(1, "days")
  .format("DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss");
let yesterDay = moment
  .tz(selectedDate, "America/Chicago")
  .subtract(1, "days")
  .format("DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss");
console.log("Previous", yesterDay);
console.log("Current", formattedDate);
console.log("Next", nextDay);
```

```html
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.23/moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022.min.js"></script>
```